# Mysql Workbench bug when using many sum() aggregation functions in same Sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

This is a part of a system's database I'm developing:

[my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2cWm.png)

I need to create an SQL statement that returns the name of the Client and the total of ALL the Sales for this respective Client. In other words, the amount of money the Client has spent in Sales.

Let's create an example:

```
Table client:
cliId = 1, cliName = "client1";

Table product:
proId = 1, proName = "prod1", proBaseValue = 3;
proId = 2, proName = "prod2", proBaseValue = 2.5;
proId = 3, proName = "prod3", proBaseValue = 1;

Table sale:
salId = 1, salAddition = 0, salDiscount = 1, sal_cliId = 1;
salId = 2, salAddition = 2, salDiscount = 0, sal_cliId = 1;
salId = 3, salAddition = 0, salDiscount = 2, sal_cliId = 1;

Table saleitems (Weak Entity from the relationship between sale and product):
sli_salId = 1, sli_proId = 2, sliRealValue = 2.5, sliQuantity = 1;
sli_salId = 2, sli_proId = 2, sliRealValue = 2.5, sliQuantity = 2;
sli_salId = 2, sli_proId = 3, sliRealValue = 1,   sliQuantity = 1;
sli_salId = 3, sli_proId = 1, sliRealValue = 3,   sliQuantity = 1;
sli_salId = 3, sli_proId = 2, sliRealValue = 2.5, sliQuantity = 1;
sli_salId = 3, sli_proId = 3, sliRealValue = 1,   sliQuantity = 2;
```

In a 1st situation, ignoring the "salAddition" and "salDiscount", I came with the following SQL statement:

```
select cliName, (sum(sliRealValue * sliQuantity))
from exampledb.client join exampledb.sale join exampledb.saleitems
where cliId = sal_cliId and
salId = sli_salId
group by cliId;
```

And it worked perfectly. BUT **the problem is when I try to include the "salAddition" and "salDiscount" to the math**. Theoretically, the SQL statement for this would be:

```
select cliName, (sum(sliRealValue * sliQuantity) + sum(salAddition) - sum(salDiscount))
from exampledb.client join exampledb.sale join exampledb.saleitems
where cliId = sal_cliId and
salId = sli_salId
group by cliId;
```

Notice that I need to sum all the additions and all the discounts from all sales to make it work. That wasn't straightforward...

According to the example given above, ignoring the additional values and the discounts, the expected total value would be $16, and including these attributes, the total should be $15, BUT the result I'm finding is 13$.
After a few hours testing the codes and value combinations, I noticed that, in the first sale, **the addition and discount values are being multiplied** by 1, in the second sale, the same values are being multiplied by 2, in the third sale, the values are being multiplied by 3 and so on...(and no, it's not related to the Id value).

I tried to replace the `...+ sum(salAddition) - sum(salDiscount)...` by `...+ sum(salAddition - salDiscount)...` But I'm finding the same value (and problem).

Please, can anyone tell me what the BUG is going on and, if possible, tell me a way to fix this problem? Did I just find a bug in MySQL Workbench?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sql statement is executed by mysql, not mysql workbench, so this cannot be a bug in the workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you did not specifically write, but the math only works out if the additional amount and the discount is applied per sale, not per product per sale. However, since you sum up the additional amount and the discount per product. Just check your query without group by and the sums to fully understand.

This means, you have to first sum the real value per sale, then add and subtract the additional stuff and the discount.

```
select c.cliName, sum(t.salevalue+s.salAddition-s.discount) as totalsalevalue
from (select sli_salId, sum(sliRealValue * sliQuantity) as salevalue
      from saleitems
      group by sli_salId) t
inner join sale s on t.sli_salId=s.salId
inner join client c on c.cliId=s.sal_cliId
group by c.cliId
```

Two comments:

1. Pls use the explicit `join` syntax, where the join condition is in the `on` clause, not in the `where`. Performance wise there is no difference, but makes your code easier to read.
2. Under SQL99 standard you are allowed to have fields in the select list that are not in the group by list, nor are aggregated, provided they are functionally dependent on the field(s) in the group by list. Mysql follows this standard since mysql v5.7.5, so you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks. It worked!! But still, can you explain your 2nd comment a little more for us? Also, I'm sorry for not putting the join conditions in the `on` clause. Indeed, it makes the code way more beautiful. Thanks again!

Comment: The query first sums up the saleitems per sale, so that you have a single line per sale. This happens in the subquery. Then it joins the sales table with the discount and the addtional amount. This prevents the duplication of the additional amount and the discount. As I wrote, run your original query without the summing up and group by and you will understand what went wrong.